# Either @sys.date-period or @sys.date

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to be able to handle an `intent` where the user provides either a date period or a date in their phrase.

E.g., "What's my scheduled `today`" or "What's my schedule `this week`".

Using `@sys.date-period` serves an empty parameter to my webhook when "today" is used, and using `@sys.date` serves an empty parameter when "this week" is used.

Is there a way to accomplish this other than using `@sys.any` and deciphering the type of parameter myself in my fulfillment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@sys.date-time` entity to get the date, I'm using it in my bot and it's working fine with any of the cases that you've mentioned.

It easily identifies `today`, `tomorrow` or general date format (i.e. 21st Jan).

For more information see [this documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities)

Comment: Awesome. I flat overlooked that. Will test now. Thank you!

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, Happy to help you :)